How to comment the variables declared by destructuring so that the description is displayed when the mouse hovers over them
I tried adding a description but it didn't work, No matter how I annotate it it will only show the type.
Neither of the following methods work.
// not working
/** not working */
const [state, setState] = useState(0)


But this is available on normal variables, Like this


what if you use @type {[int, int]}

This question is similar to: React Hooks - JSDoc with destructured array variables and How do I document useState hooks with JSDoc?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

use typedef
@typedef {int} state - state description
@type {[state]}
it works


It worked after I used @typedef
